# Why was memory keyword used in this example

Tags: solidity

I am doing the [cryptozombies.io](https://cryptozombies.io/) course on Solidity.

In Chapter 7 of Making the Zombie Factory, it introduces function declarations. The instructions on this chapter are:

> Create a public function named createZombie. It should take two parameters: _name (a string), and _dna (a uint). Don't forget to pass the first argument by value by using the memory keyword

My question is why is the `_name` parameter required to be declared with keyword `memory` (and similarly, why is the `_dna` parameter NOT required to be declared with keyword `memory`)?

In general, when does one declare a parameter using keyword `memory` and without it? I did [Google about the `memory` keyword](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#storage-memory-and-the-stack) but I did not understand when it should be used and when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsigned Integer or integers do not require memory specification when declared as arguments. Strings, arrays and structs require memory specification.